# My function doesn't display the alert (preventDefault)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alert, preventdefault

I am working on a to-do list app (React.js) and trying to make use of the preventDefault function. I've added an onSubmit attribute to my form element and want it to display an alert when the add button is clicked. Problem is it doesn't seem to work, here's my code

```
function Form (props) {
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Added')
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h2 className="label-wrapper">
          <label htmlFor="new-todo-input" className="label-lg">
            What needs to be done?
          </label>
        </h2>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="new-todo-input"
          className="input input-lg"
          name="text"
          autoComplete="off"
        ></input>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn__lg">
          Add
        </button>
      </form>
  )
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: This code works as-is and will alert "Added" when the form is submitted.

Comment: But when I click the add button, I don't get the alert and the browser seems to refresh very quickly?

Comment: The code presented as in the question works. Please may you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the issue you're seeing?

Comment: If the page is refreshing quickly that could mean that `preventDefault` isn't working.

Comment: I have checked the code it's working fine. Please check for any spelling errors.

Comment: I think I've found the issue - the component that I've shared (Form.js) doesn't seem to be imported in App.js. The line where I've imported it looks faded and I'm getting a warning saying "'Form' is defined but never used ". Any ideas how to fix that? All the other components are imported the same way and the path is correct.

Comment: have you tried restarting your server @SüleymanEminbəyli ? You're code is working fine, no errors here.